# Access Vision Prescription metadata from HKSampleQueryDescription

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, ios16

I want to query HealthKit for Vision Prescriptions.

I have created these vision prescriptions programmatically and I am attempting to write a query for HealthKit so that I can retrieve them.

I am able to query the prescription records, but not able to access all the metadata about the prescription such as the `HKGlassesLensSpecification` for both eyes.

I created these record programmatically so I know the values I am looking for exist and I am able to confirm their existence in the Health app.

The query below is able to return results back that I have saved to HealthKit, however, I am having trouble accessing the HKVisionPrescription metadata such as the HKGlassesLensSpecification for both the Right and Left Eye. I am only able to access properties like prescriptionType and dateIssued.

```
func getPrescriptions() async -> [HKVisionPrescription] {
        let datePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: start, end: end)

        // Predicate that matches vision prescriptions samples
        let predicate = HKSamplePredicate.visionPrescription(datePredicate)

        let descriptor = HKSampleQueryDescriptor(
            predicates:[predicate],
            sortDescriptors: [],
            limit: 10)
        
        do {
            let results = try await descriptor.result(for: store)
            
            if results.isEmpty {
                return []
            }
            
            results.forEach { prescription in
                // How to access prescription metadata here?
            }
            return results
            
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
```

Edit: I noticed a metadata property on the HKVisionPrescription... is this a place where I can store the properties for each prescription?